# Extract the Absolute / Relative Path to a Folder Up in The Tree

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, path

I use the code [Resolve Absolute Path from Relative Path and / or File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404867) in order to extract absolute path from relative path.

Yet my question is how to extract the relative / absolute path of a folder up the tree but at unknown level.
Assume the following folder tree (Is there a tool to generate those?):

```
- SomeFolder
---- FolderA
------------ FolderAA
------------ FolderAB
---- FolderB
------------ FolderBA
---------------- FolderBAA
---------------- FolderBAB
------------ FolderBB
---------------- FolderBBA
-------------------- FolderBBAA
-------------------- FolderBBAB
---------------- FolderBBB
```

So I am at, `FolderBBAA`, `FolderBAA` or `FolderAA`.
I am after the absolute path for `FolderA`.

So I'm looking for a Batch Function which goes up (Just up, it doesn't go down) the tree until it finds the folder named by a given name and then returns the absolute folder to the folder.

How could one write such function for a Batch File?

**Remark**: Pay attention that the folder looked for might not be part of the path to the `pwd` folder. So at each level the function should look on the folders of that level (But not inside them).

#### Pseudo Code

```matlab
function [ relPathToFolder ] = SearchFolder( targetFolderName )

relPathToFolder = "None"; %<! Or any other value for the case not found
currFolder = "./";

% If in the currecnt working folder
currFolderItems = dir();
if targetFolderName in currFolderItems
  relPathToFolder = currFolder + targetFolderName;
  return;
end

% Going up until it is found
while(currFolder is not root)

  currFolder = relPathToFolder + "../";
  currFolderItems = dir(currFolder)

  if targetFolderName in currFolderItems
    relPathToFolder = currFolder + targetFolderName;
    return
  end

% If not found returning the not found string

end
```

Comment: Think of the general case, I just want to go up in the tree and look for a folder. I don't know at which level the folder I'm looking for is (How many times to go up, maybe one, two, etc...).

Comment: I'd better have it in the same format as the function I linked above. I'd like to use it within existing batch file.

Comment: So sorry, but this is not bat/cmd and I don’t know how can I help you. Talves
 you're using a pseudo code that only you understand, I don't know what language it is. Forgive me for take your time...

Comment: I prefer to delete my reply, thus avoiding further down and polluting your post. I hope you understand me.

Comment: @It Wasn't Me: Talves you're using a pseudo code ??????? LOL

Comment: @RicardoBohner I’m definitely using a pseudo misunderstanding of the issue!? ;-)  ...

Comment: It is difficult to answer when your edits (and comments) change the original question.

Comment: Your example():= does not make():= clear(;), and does not resemble anything with command(~):= or functions() -:bat....

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: The question has never been changed. Why do you think so? The tree above was the same from the beginning. Nothing has changed.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe, Why do you say the edits changed the question? They did not change anything.  The only thing I changed is I don't mind getting relative or absolute path (As I linked to a function to convert relative to absolute).

Comment: @DavidPostill, Please read carefully the question. It hasn't changed. From the first case I asked for something that will resolve `FolderA`  when I'm at `FolderBBAA` which require at each level to look at all folders. The only thing I changed is I don't mind having relative or absolute since I have a way to convert relative to absolute.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe, There is no need to explain. Just please don't say things which are wrong. The question hasn't changed. The question was never about searching within the path string. It was a bout searching a folder at the current level and go up.

Comment: 1° version: Get full path from (exist) folder up 2° version: Get full path folder up (if exist) 3° version: Get full path (+ relative path) folder up (if exist)... see for your self

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe, You're wrong. Look at 1st version. It was about getting `FolderA` from `FolderBBAA`. How can you do that without looking at the folders at each level? Look yourself and see I haven't touched it and it was like that from 1st version. If I was only asking for going up then I'd ask how to capture part of a string not looking at folders. I don't care for absolute or relative path. I will mark an answer with either.

Comment: To do this without looking at each level is pure simple and easy, but this will require from you to do lot meditation brow!  ;) ....

Comment: How can you do this without looking at the folders at each level? It seems you took the concept of the folders as this is the only case while it was just an example. In reality the names of the folder and the tree can be different. If there is only the above case, no need for a function, you can just use the specific solution.

Comment: Is possible only if you have a unique name for this folder...

Comment: Is it written anywhere to assume special name? We're after functions, namely things are parameterized.

Comment: I’m not understanding your last comment..sorry

Comment: You say you assume the folder names are hard coded. I wrote that if things are are hard coded there is no need to write a function.  The idea is to write a function that will be able to function on any folder tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the way, the parser works to "split" the current folder (`%cd%`) into the desired base path and "commenting out" the rest:

```
set folder=%cd:\SomeFolder\=\SomeFolder&REM %
echo %folder%
```

Run it with `echo off` to watch the "magic" happen.

Read the output of `set /?` to learn how the substring substitution works.

If `somefolder` isn't found, nothing is replaced and it returns the current working folder.

**EDIT**
I hope I understood you correctly this time:

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "%~dp0"
:loop
  dir /ad "%~nx1" >nul 2>&1&& goto :found
  if "%cd:~3,1%" == "" echo not found & goto :eof
  cd ..
  set "rel=..\%rel%"

goto :loop
:found
set "found=%cd%\%~nx1"
echo absolute folder is "%found:\\=\%"
echo relative folder is "%rel%%~nx1"
popd
pause
```

See if `FolderA` is a child of the current folder. If not, go up one folder and repeat.
Break the loop, if you are at the root of the drive (`X:\`) and still haven't found it.

The replacement of `\\` with `\` is necessary, because `%CD%` gives a trailing backslash at the root, but not anywhere else.

The searched folder is given as a parameter to the batchfile (also drop/drag onto the batchfile works).

Comment: Am I mistaken to understand your code only looks if the searched for folder is part of the path? But ic could be a sub folder of a folder in the path and the code won't find it.

Comment: Your question says only "up the path" (straight line). If we have to look into "sibling folders" at any point, this changes the question completely. Please clarify (preferably in the question itself)

Comment: How can you find `FolderA` from `FolderBBAA` without looking at sub folders? I said you only go up and look for folders at that level, not going down again into them. That was how the question was phrased from the beginning (If you want, it only looks one level down each time it goes up).

Comment: Maybe you are mistaken "Subfolders" with "Parent"....users (Parent) -> username (current Folder) -> Desktop (subfolder)..

Comment: Ah - I (mis)understood `SomeFolder` to be a fixed known name.

Comment: All names are parameters. I just need a function which starts at the location of the script and goes up. At each level looks for a folder named `SomeInputParameter`.

Comment: use `cd "%~dp0` to change to the location of your script and change `set "LookFor=FolderA"` to `set "LookFor=SomeInputParameter"`

Comment: @Royi: I just realized you want both the absolute and the relative path. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't need both. In case I get the relative I linked to a function which converts it into absolute. I am just not sure how your script works.

Comment: pretty much like your pseudo-code: see if the searched folder is a child of the current folder. If not, go up one folder and repeat until found (or there isn't any "up" anymore)

Answer (score 2):

I updated the answer, now it also searches in sub-folders of the parent and child folders. MaxLevel is a delimiter for parent folders meaning don't go any deeper than that "parent folder"

For example if you have "Folder_F" as input and want to search for a folder called "my folder" and MaxLevel is "Desktop". It would only search for "my folder" up to Desktop and it's sub-folders and return a "Not Found" if the folder wasn't there. The reason for MaxLevel is to avoid very long search time that might include whole drives and more.

"C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Folder_A\Folder_B\Folder_C\Folder_D\Folder_E\Folder_F"

The search is stored in a funcion called GetParent so you can do a call Getparent.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
mode con: cols=120 Lines=15
echo.
IF /i exist "%~1" (set "CurrentPath=%~1") else (set /p "CurrentPath=%BS% Please input the Path you want to verify: ")

:Start
set RelPath=
set RelPath2=
set Parent=
set AbsPath=

cls
echo.
echo  Current Path Analysed: "%CurrentPath%"
echo.
set /p "Parent=%BS% Please Input the Parent Folder: "
echo.
IF not Defined MaxLevel set /p "MaxLevel=%BS% Please Input Max Level Folder: "
pushd "%CurrentPath%"

Call :GetParent

:GetParent
cls
echo.
echo  Current Path Analysed: "%CurrentPath%"
echo.
echo  Searching for: "%Parent%"
echo.
echo  Max Level: "%Maxlevel%"
echo.
echo  Currently Scanning: "%CD%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad ^&echo %CD%') do (                                              
                                                          IF /i "%CD:~-1%"=="\" (
                                                                                 echo.
                                                                                 Echo  Parent Folder not Found^^!
                                                                                 echo.
                                                                                 pause > nul | set /p="%BS% Press any key to continue..."
                                                                                 goto :End
                                                                                )
                                                          IF /i "%%~nxa"=="%Parent%" (
                                                                                      set "AbsPath=%%~dpnxa"
                                                                                      set "RelPath=!RelPath!"
                                                                                      set "RelPath2=!AbsPath:%CD%=!"
                                                                                      IF /i "!RelPath2!"=="" set "RelPath2=%%~nxa"& set "RelPath=..\!RelPath!"
                                                                                      set "RelPath=!RelPath!!RelPath2!"
                                                      set "RelPath=!RelPath:\\=\!"
                                                                                      echo.
                                                                                      echo  Relative path: "!RelPath!"
                                                                                      echo  Absolute path: "!AbsPath!"
                                                                                      echo.
                                                                                      pause > nul | set /p="%BS% Press any key to continue..."
                                                                                      goto :End
                                                                                     )
                                                          IF /i "%%~nxa"=="%Maxlevel%" (
                                                                                        echo.
                                                                                        Echo  Parent Folder not Found^^!
                                                                                        echo.
                                                                                        pause > nul | set /p="%BS% Press any key to continue..."
                                                                                        goto :End
                                                                                       )
                                                        )
cd ..
set "RelPath=..\%RelPath%"
goto :GetParent

:End
 echo.
echo.
set /p "Repeat=%BS% Go Again? (y) (n): "
If "%Repeat%"=="y" goto :Start
exit
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6ezyd1u.gif]

Comment: Could it be in a form like https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404867? Namely it is under `:call` block and sets a variable which can be used later?

Comment: Does the code looks for all sub folders of the current folder it looks at?

Comment: It depends on what subfolder you drag & drop to the batch. It actually searches only for parent folders not for subfolders. Basically it does a "CD.." (go up 1 level), than a "CD" (check current parent),CD,CD..,CD,CD....and so on.IF the current parent is the folder you are searching for it shows the path. I add that call: & save in variable part later...

Comment: Have you looked on the cases I posted in the question? The `pseudo code`? It is not only if the folder name is in the path of the current folder.

Comment: Yes I looked but apparently I didn't fully understand it. So it should search for a given Folder in Parent folders and in Subfolders?

Comment: Lets say the current Folder is "Desktop" should it look only in subfolders of desktop or all subfolders of the parents also? Cause if its the second option than basically you want to search for a folder in the whole drive c:\*.*

Comment: Assume being on a folder in a Drive, not desktop. You;re looking for `FolderA`. First you look at all folders at the current folder level (All folders listed with `dir()` command). If you find it, great, then the output is `./FolderA`. If you didn't find and you're not on root you go one level up. You look at all folders at that level (Folders in `dir()`). If you find `FolderA` then the output is `./../FolderA` if not and not yet on root go up one level and do over...

Comment: I think I got it now. But why are you using Linux slashes? Wouldn't it be .\..\FolderA for Windows?

Comment: Would that part in "Relative Path" be the expected output? https://s3.gifyu.com/images/Get-Parent-Folder-03.gif

Comment: But the folder I'm looking for might not be in the path itself. So you need to build folders as I built in the question.

Comment: It also searches in subfolders of the parent now. I'm updating my answer....

Comment: I don't need to search sub folders only the folders at the current level (Current level changes always up one folder). Is my pseudo code clear?

Answer (score 1):

- `/* EDIT`

> *So I'm looking for a Batch Function which goes up*...

The follow below of this edition, attentive to answer, but assuming that I will use it only once, you can also use it that way...

```cmd
rem :: Your code where it is necessary to
rem :: find/define the folder in the variable %_dir%, add:

set^ "_up=..\" 
set^ "_cd=FolderA"

%:^(
for /d /r %_up% %%i in =;(*
     =;)do if /i "%%~nxi" == "%_cd%" =;(
          set^ "_dir=%%~fi" && goto %:^)
     =;)

=;<con: set^ "_up=%_up%..\" && goto %:^(

rem :: Your code where you continue from 
rem :: that point using the variable %_dir%
```

- `*/ EDIT`

---

```cmd
%:^/
set^ "_up=..\"

%:^(
for /d /r %_up% %%i in =;(*
     =;)do if /i "%%~nxi" == "%~nx1" =;(
           set "_dir=%%~fi" && goto %:^)
     =;)

call set^ "_up=%_up%..\" && goto %:^(
```

- Above a function that uses a loop to find folder `"FolderA"` and define `_dir` with the full path to your folder passed in the argument `%~1`, in: `call %:^/ "FolderA"`..

---

```cmd
@echo off 

rem :: actual bat code :: 
rem :: actual bat code :: 
rem :: ............... ::
rem :: final code in your bat code :: 
rem :: if using setlocal, endlocal :: 

endlocal & exit /b || goto :eof 

rem :: its function starts below
rem :: just call function "folderName"   
rem :: call %:^/ ["Folder_Name_To_Find"] 

%:^/
set^ "_up=..\"

%:^(
for /d %%i in =;(%_up%*
    =;)do if /i "%%~nxi" == "%~nx1" =;(
          cd /d "%%~dpnxi" && goto %:^) 
        =;)

call set^ "_up=%_up%..\" && goto %:^(

%:^)
echo\Here I'm %CD% & exit /b
```

---

**1.** Define this `..\` (relative path) to `_up` string in a var for loop and increment after `for /d ()` not find your folde name:

```cmd
set^ "_up=..\"
for /Directory loop in (..\) 
              next loop in (..\..\)
                    next loop in (..\..\..\)
                              next loop in (so on...)
call set^ "_up=%_up%..\"  ==> ..\ + ..\
```

**2.** Your argument `%1` to function name is `%~nx1` and if the name matches to the current folder name `%%~nxi`**<sup>1</sup>**,  you are *"goo to go"* `goto %:^)`**<sup>2</sup>**...

```cmd
if /i "%%~nxi" =="%~nx1" =;(
         cd /d "%%~dpnxi" && goto %:^)
```

**Obs.: 1** Even looking for folder **`~Name`** only, the use with looped files expands **`%~nxi`** to Name + eXtension, but when it comes to looped **folders**, it is recommended...

- ```cmd
  Period/Full Stop
  Although Win32 will not recognize any file or directory name that begins or
  ends with a '.' (period / full stop) it is possible to include a Full Stop
  in the middle of a directory name and this can cause issues with FOR /D.
  ‍
  Parameter expansion will treat a Full Stop as a file extension, so for a
  directory name like "Sample 2.6.4" the output of %%~nG will be truncated
  to "Sample 2.6" to return the whole folder name use %%G or %%~nxG
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

**Obs.: 2** You can also exit the function at this point... replace this  code to **`exit /b`**

```cmd
..)do if /i "%%~nxi" == "%~nx1" =;(
      cd /d "%%~dpnxi" && goto %:^) exit /b
    =;)

call set^ "_up=%_up%..\" && goto %:^(

%:^)
echo\Here I'm %CD% & exit /b
```

---

- Conventional layout:

```cmd
@echo off 

rem :: actual bat code :: 
rem :: actual bat code :: 
rem :: ............... ::
rem :: final code in your bat code :: 
rem :: if using setlocal, endlocal :: 

endlocal
exit /b || goto :eof 

rem :: its function starts below
rem :: just call function "folderName"   
rem :: call :main_loop ["Folder_Name_To_Find"] 

:main_loop
set "_up=..\"

:loop_folder
for /d %%i in (%_up%*) do (
     if /i "%%~nxi" == "%~nx1" (
         cd /d "%%~dpnxi"
         goto :loop_out
        )
    )

call set "_up=%_up%..\"
goto :loop_folder

:loop_out
echo\Here I'm %CD%
exit /b
```

---

- Adding recursivity to your loop:

  - ```cmd
    FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
    FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
    ```
  - ```cmd
    The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
    while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
    match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
    Note: Source linked to ss64.com
    ```

```cmd
...

%:^/
set^ "_up=..\"

%:^(
for /d /r %_up% %%i in =;(*)do if "%%~nxi"=="%~nx1" =;(
         cd /d "%%~fi" && set "_dir=%%~fi" && goto %:^)
     =;)

call set^ "_up=%_up%..\" && goto %:^(

%:^)
echo\Here I'm %CD%
```

```cmd
...

:main_loop
set "_up=..\"

:loop_folder
for /d /r %_up% %%i in (*) do (
     if /i "%%~nxi" == "%~nx1" (
         cd /d "%%~dpnxi"
         set "_dir=%%~fi"
         goto :loop_out
        )
    )

call set "_up=%_up%..\"
goto :loop_folder

:loop_out
echo\Here I'm %CD%
exit /b
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /D /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [`For /R /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [`If condition() else condition()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Command line parameters in batch file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)
- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file)

Comment: If you could give me a single solution in the form of something like: https://pastebin.com/f7Xy0mjD. Something I can call and it returns the relative path to the folder (Or `NONE` if not find).

Comment: @Royi Good point, i've not think in 'if not find' condition.. I will see in + 1-2 h ..

Comment: @Royi without having at least the name of a folder above to take it as a limit, the search / scan to affirm that  (Folder_A) it does not exist, will go / go through many folders to the root

Comment: @Royi Would it be valid to assume the folder where the bat itself is (`%~f0`) as the above folder as the search limit for searching the target folder, and if not finding it can say that the target folder does not exist?

Comment: I think it is OK to go up until you reach the root. If you want, you can set a parameter to the number of times to go up (Input Parameter).

Comment: @Royi I'm testing [this](https://pastebin.com/Y2gWivnK)

Comment: I added a pseudo code. Looking at the edit you made to my question I'm not sure you got it right.